# Why does $\frac{(x+2)\cdot (2x+\frac{1}{x^2})-(x^2-\frac{1}{x})\cdot 1}{(x+2)^2}$ simplify to $\frac{x^4+4x^3+2x+2}{x^2(x+2)^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I have been burdened with an unclear textbook. The exercise is to differentiate the fraction of two functions. Here it is:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{x}}{x+2}$$

I understand how to do this: $\left ( \frac{a}{b} \right )'=\frac{ba'-ab'}{b^2}$. I have that memorised, and for step one me and the textbook agree. Here's the textbook solution:

$$f'(x)=\frac{(x+2)\cdot (2x+\frac{1}{x^2})-(x^2-\frac{1}{x})\cdot 1}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{x^4+4x^3+2x+2}{x^2(x+2)^2}$$

Now here's my solution:

$$f'(x)=\frac{(x+2)\cdot (2x+x^{-2})-(x^2-x^{-1})\cdot 1}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{2x^2+x^{-1}+4x+2x{-2}-x^2+x^{-1}}{x^2+4x+4}=\frac{x^2+4x+2x^{-1}+2x^{-2}}{x^2+4x+4}$$

My approach is simple: I write instances of $1/x^n$ with negative exponents, multiply everything in brackets until there's no more brackets, then I add together the terms with the same exponent and order them from high to low. I understand that brackets are necessary if you want to keep multiplication factors intact (for instance to figure out for what values of x the result is zero) but then I might as well not have done anything. The textbook clearly goes for something else entirely, and its approach I truly cannot devise.

I know that these two answers are equivalent. [Wolfram Alpha agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28x%2B2%29*%282x%2B%281%2Fx%5E2%29%29-%28x%5E2-%281%2Fx%29%29%29%2F%28x%2B2%29%5E2%3D%28x%5E2%2B4x%2B2x%5E-1%2B2x%5E-2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B4x%2B4%29). My question is, *why* would one go for the textbook notation when *simplifying* the immediate solution (the step me and my textbook agree on). This is a consistent problem I have with the textbook; my answers end up equivalent to the textbook answer but entirely differently notated. I feel like there's something I am missing, for when I ask Wolfram to differentiate the original fraction, [it too ends up with the textbook notation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=differentiate%20%28Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-1%2Fx%29%2F%28x%2B2%29).

I don't have a tutor to ask; I am working my way through the book on my own in preparation for a programming course. This feels critical to me; what are the steps to reach the textbook solution, and most importantly *why* are those the steps to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nota bene: (a - b) / c  = (xa - xb) / xc

Looks to me your textbook solution went with multiplying by x^2 as to get rid of fractions in the numerator.

Wouldn't say though that in the e.g. any one approach being superior over the other, rather a matter of taste, really.

However, textbooks way can come in handy when dealing with terms not so neatly designed as in e.g.

Comment: Wow! Looks like that was in fact the only step I missed. That, and I got rid of the brackets in the denominator while they kept that term squared.